# Words order: 我们两个是好朋友

Tags: word-order

I faced sentence with word order that is different from expected "我们两个是好朋友" instead of "我们是两个好朋友". Does it have some different meaning?

Comment: A more concise way to say it would be 我們倆很要好

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not much of a different depends on the question asked if this is an answer:

```
我们两个是好朋友 - Us two are good friends  

我们是两个好朋友 - We are two good friends
```

Comment: I'd say 我们是两个好朋友 is a rare expression. Sounds a bit odd to me. If you want to emphasize on the 好朋友 part, you usually want to say "我们是好朋友". If you want to emphasize on the 我们两个 part, you could say 我们两个是好朋友.

Answer (score 4):

As Ben Yang pointed out, 我们是两个好朋友 is not quite idiomatic. It's because 两个好朋友 (two good friends) is not a **unity**. You can say 我们是一对好姐妹；我们是一对夫妻，where 一对好姐妹 or 一对夫妻 is a unity.

我们两个是好朋友 is idiomatic, meaning *we two are good friends*.